# Find the value of $n$

Tags: trigonometry

Let $P$ be a point inside the regular polygon of $20$ sides such that each side equal to $1$. Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{20}$ denote the distances of $P$ from the sides of the polygon then 
$$
  \frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{x_2} + \frac{1}{x_3} + 
\dots + \frac{1}{x_{20}} = n \pi
$$

If $n$ is an integer, how to find the value of $n$? What I am finding strange is how to get that $\pi$ term.

Update:I think my book has some printing error.Because in the answer it is given n<2.

So I think this will be the correct question:

$$
  \frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{x_2} + \frac{1}{x_3} + 
\dots + \frac{1}{x_{20}} > n \pi
$$

Now find the largest possible integer value of n.

Comment: Can you clarify how you are defining the *distance from $P$ to a side of the polygon*?

Comment: I guess geometrical distance of P from each side of polygon individually...@MikePierce

Comment: So, are we talking the shortest distance between $P$ and any point on a given side, or the perpendicular distance between the extension of that side (to a line) to $P$?

Comment: I guess the shortest distance (i.e. perpendicular distance ).... @MikePierce

Comment: The formula cannot be right, for rational $n$ or even algebraic $n$.

Comment: I agree @AndréNicolas....maybe there's a printing mistake....because in the answer its given n<2....is it now possible?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta You still haven't answered Mike's question.  In many cases the shortest distance from a point to a side will **not** be a perpendicular distance.  Consider the side from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$ and the point $(10,10)$.  What's the distance?  Is it $10$ or is it $\sqrt{10^2+9^2}$?

Comment: which book are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim the statement is not true.  Let $P$ be rather close to side $1$.  We can make $\frac 1{x_1}$ arbitrarily large. If we want $n=1000$, we choose a point $\frac 1{1000 \pi}$ from the side, near the center, then move away from the side enough to account for the other $19$ terms.  We can do the same for $n=10,000$  Given any $n$ large enough, we can find a $P$ that satisfies it.

To find (very heuristically) the minimum $n$, pretend the polygon is a circle with circumference $20$.  Each of the $x_i$ is then $\frac {10}\pi$ and the sum on the left is $2\pi$.  Since the sides are in fact straight, the $x_i$ will be a little smaller and all the terms on the left will be a little larger.  I would guess that we cannot have $n=2$, but we can have any larger $n$.

Comment: THUMBS UP FOR THE AWESOME ANSWER :-D!!!